# Would I need a hacked PSP to run custom translation patches?

Tags: psp

There's currently work being done for the Puela Magi Madoka Magica PSP Game to have an English translation. It's still not done yet. However, in general, if a Japanese PSP game had an English patch for it, would I need a hacked PSP?

Comment: It would depend. If it's an official thing released in your region, then I would assume not. If you're importing it, then probably. Region locking is complicated.

Comment: PSP doens't have any region lock for games.

Comment: @Unionhawk well if the game was officially released in my region that it would have been localized for English players meaning an English interface so a translation patch would not be required

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how the translation will be released.

PSP doens't have any regional locking for games, so technically a Japanese game on UMD or downloaded from the Japanese PSN store should work on any PSP without a problem.

If the translation doesn't require modifying the game image in any way (for example, if it's an official release or *theoretically* a bootleg UMD or a modified save file), you should be good to go; if, however, you need a patched UMD ISO/CSO, then you'll need a modded PSP, capable of running games from outside sources.

Comment: Really? Are there any translation patches that don't require modifying the game image? Would be fascinating to discover any that  did.

Comment: I think "custom translation" pretty much rules out official releases. Never heard of save-based translations either.

Comment: It was meant as a theoretical example. 
What I meant was basically that if the "patch" only modifies user-accessible features of the game - in the case of PSP games, the save - then you wouldn't need to mod your PSP. 
I know there were instances in the past where fan translation were pressed into bootleg cartridges which allowed them to run on unmodded consoles. I'm pretty sure there isn't a way to bootleg UMDs, though.

Comment: Do you really think it's helpful to put a theoretical example in the middle of an answer without at least noting it as such?

Comment: Noted. That's why I edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the size of the game. Games under 1142MB can be signed with a demo key to run on any PSP updated to the official 6.60 firmware and up (smaller games can be signed to run on earlier versions of the firmware). This method can be used to run homebrew software and fan translations without cracking your PSP.

The program used to sign games that way is called Fake NP, you can find it using Google.

Games over 1142MB can't be signed that way and will require a custom firmware or some other modification to run, at least until Sony releases a demo that is larger than 1142MB.

Comment: That's interesting, never heard of this before. Then again I've been out of the modding loop for a while. I think maybe a link to a guide showing this method would benefit the answer

Comment: @JohnoBoy it could, but I'm not sure how a link to a DRM circumvention tutorial would be interpreted by the idiotic copyright laws SE has to abide by.

Comment: It's borderline piracy talk, I assume, especially since in this example, it's being used for a "valid" reason...